# Determining which primes satisfy a set of quadratic divisibility conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, quadratic-reciprocity

I have a [hypothetical] prime $\phi$ which satisfies the divisibility conditions
$$\phi \mid (2a^2-1)$$
$$\phi \mid (b^2-2)$$
$$\phi \mid (c^2-8)$$
$$\phi \mid (2d^2-289)$$
$$\phi \mid (e^2-1682)$$
$$\phi \mid (f^2-29),$$
where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are positive integers.

What is the optimal way to determine the set of primes that $\phi$ could be drawn from? I’m assuming quadratic reciprocity is involved…?

Comment: Sure.  Note that many of your conditions are redundant.  $2$ is a square $\pmod {\phi}$ iff any only if $2^{-1}$ is, and if and only if $8$ is, so the first three conditions are the same.  As is the fourth, since $289=17^2$ is obviously a square.  and $682=2\times 29^2$ is a square if and only if $2$ is, so that is redundant as well.  So, really, you just need $2$ and $29$ to be squares.